# Pregunta acerca de scroll - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un botón como parte del contenido de un archivo html -> éste a su vez dentro de un iframe -> el iframe a su vez dentro de la página web madre.

¿Cómo puedo indicarle con jquery al botón que haga que la página madre que contiene todo haga un scroll hasta arriba con `animation` y con velocidad `fast` ?

Comment: Hola psy, puedes poner el codigo que **has intentado** y el HTML que explicas del frame y el resto de elementos?

Comment: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast"); sería esta idea pero que en vez de hacérselo al html se lo haga a la página madre que contiene el iframe. @lois6b

Comment: No lo pongas en los comentaros, edita la pregunta.  Y añade el html

Comment: Hola, coloca el codigo html completo y el js para ver como lo haces

Comment: @lois6b - el html que contiene el botón está dentro de un iframe dentro de una página madre wordpress (no sé si está permitido linkear páginas externas de wordpress para que lo puedas ver). Pero básicamente lo que quiero es que haciendo click en el botón dentro del iframe, suba mediante jquery hasta arriba la página del wordpress con una animación rápida.

Comment: Debes acceder al objeto `window` padre mediante `window.parent` y a partir de alli seleccionar el body: `$(window.parent.document.body).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');`.

Comment: @GustavoGracía era eso, me sirve, muchísimas gracias! :)

Comment: Añade lo que habías intentado a tu pregunta para mover mi comentario a respuesta y que la marques. Algunas personas tendrán el mismo problema.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía no parece que el autor vaya ha hacer nada ahora que encontró la solucion.. vas a ponerlo como respuesta para que quede constancia para futuros users?

Comment: @lois6b No estoy seguro si debería. ¿Qué opinas?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía sip. yo lo haría en tu posición

Comment: @lois6b Hecho :P

Answer (score 1):

Debes acceder al objeto window padre mediante [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent). El objeto `window` general no tiene un padre, solo lo tienen los iframes, object o el obsoleto, frame. A partir de alli seleccionar el body para animarlo:

```
$(window.parent.document.body).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```